Present continuous vs present perfect continuous to express annoyance
Is there a difference in meaning between these two sentences?

He's always leaving his dirty socks on the floor.


He has been leaving his dirty socks on the floor.

The book that I use only says that present continuous can be used "when we want to express our irritation at actions which happen too often", while present perfect continuous "is used to express anger, annoyance or irritation".
I'm wondering whether these two can be used interchangeably when speaking about certain repetitive actions that annoy us and if not, what is the difference.

The second one implies (to me, at least) that it is a recently acquired habit.

To me, the second one also means that it's intermittent. The first one can be phrased as "He always leaves his dirty socks on the floor."

The book's explanation is confusing, or at least incomplete. Of course both usages "express anger, annoyance or irritation."
Perfect tenses usually talk about how the past matters to our present. So "he has been leaving his socks on the floor" is best for talking about the recent past; it suggests a change; maybe he didn't used to leave them on the floor.
The example using "always" talks about a pattern; the book's explanation that it "happens too often" could be expanded to say that it has been happening too often for some time (without being specific about how long). It's also an exaggeration. He's not literally, at every moment, dropping a sock. We can see the meaning by the fact that relationship counselors advise people not to use these kind of "always" or "never" statements. When you're arguing, "you always leave your socks on the floor" might be a colorful and forceful way to make your point, but it's not clear or accurate. It's easy for the other person to say "No I don't," since you suggested that the pattern was constant, and it's easy to say no if they just started recently, or if they ever put the socks away.
Even simple present, "He leaves his socks on the floor," has a similar meaning, making a vague statement about a general pattern, but it makes it less intensely.

Both these sentences mean the same thing but the first sentence expresses the annoyance better, partly because of the word 'always'. There is emphasis on the fact that the action has been taking place repeatedly and there is thus a greater degree of irritation.
The tense doesn't really matter in this case, you can just use the tense according to the situation. For example,

She is irritating me.
She has been irritating me.

They mean the same thing but the timing is different.
